# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/path/index.php on line 170

Tags: php

I get this error and the line 170 has this code

```
$tonton = count($veriler) - 1;
```

as more :

```
$ek = $_POST['kk']."?page=".$_POST['sayfa'];
$al = get_data("http://www.example.com/".$ek);
$dom = str_get_html($al);

$veriler = $dom->find('.videoBox');
$tonton = count($veriler) - 1;

$sondo = $_POST['adet'] + 5;

if($sondo <= count($veriler)-1)
{
    $sondon = $sondo;
}
else
{
$sondon = count($veriler) - 1;
}
```

do you have any idea where can be the problem because this script works on all my sites but only in one server I get this arror and I'm using simple_html_dom.php

with php version 5.4.34 
thankyou

Comment: Is simple_html_dom.php included in this page??

Comment: no is in the same folder but this script wordks on other servers

Comment: I have index.php save.php and html_simple_dom.php 3 files

Comment: try writing __include 'html_simple_dom.php';__ on the top of php file

Comment: so in index.php its not included but I call save.php using javascript url: 'save.php',

Comment: is it included in save.php ????

Comment: I'm trying now to add <?php include 'html_simple_dom.php';?>

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_get_html() (previously declared in /home/path/simple_html_dom.php:70) in /home/path/simple_html_dom.php on line 85

Comment: okey one more try write include_once instead of include

Comment: I tried all same error previously declared :(

Comment: Okey i went through your code and give one more try.. remove changes i said and then change few lines as i will answer.. may be this will help..

Comment: I just saw I have   <?php require('simple_html_dom.php'); in the between of index.php sorry about it

Comment: I serched on google and cannot understand where is the problem it because why this script works on my other servers and only in this server not,this is what I dont understand

Comment: LOL thanks to you i learned simple_html_dom.php

Comment: :) I'm sorry but I'm new on programming not an expert

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ek = "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/".$_POST['kk']."?page=".$_POST['sayfa'];
$dom = file_get_html($ek);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your response and time spent now the error Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/path/index.php on line 170 has gone away but now I cant list the results from the www.xxxxxsite.com so this is a bot in index.php I have a button wich lists video results from the other site with your code as I said error went away but Now I cant get results when I click the button it doesnt give me anything

Comment: maybe because I forgot $ek = $_POST['kk']."?page=".$_POST['sayfa']; to remove I'm checking now

Comment: same not listing videos :(

Comment: @Jessy i can help but not this way.. i dont know what are you working on and what you want..

Comment: but its not supported but as I said it works on all my sites only in one server I have this problem

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$dom` is not set (null). You should investigate yourself why this is the case